# CVS error - CVS exited with error code 1

Tags: ant, cygwin, cvs

I am seeing this error for quite sometime now.
I am running ant build on CYGWIN which inturn runs on WindowsXP.

The resolution(bad one) I found was to delete my gcct/first directory and run ant build again (which runs from another directory). It runs successfully but if I modify some code under gcct/first, I do not want to delete it because of this error.

I did see this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/104315/vc/Eclipse-ANT-CVS-gets-error). The resolution here does not apply to me since I do not have .cvspass defined anywhere in the build.xml.

```
C:\svn\CEL_v3681\buildCore.xml:1883: cvs exited with error code 1
Command line was [Executing 'cvs' with arguments:
'checkout'
'-A'
'-rfirst_v2_126'
'gcct/first'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.


environment:

        ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
        ANT_HOME=C:/Apps/Apache/apache-ant-1.7.0
        APPDATA=C:\Documents and Settings\shankarc\Application Data
        CLASSPATH=./;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.5.0_07/lib/ext/QTJava.zip
        COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files
        COMPUTERNAME=NYKPWM2035798
        COMSPEC=C:\WINNT\system32\cmd.exe
        CUSTPROF=Roaming700Live
        CVSROOT=:pserver:shankarc@amcvs2.lehman.com:/home/eqcvs/cmte
        CVS_RSH=/bin/ssh
        FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
        HOME=C:\Apps\CYGWIN\home\shankarc
        HOMEDRIVE=F:
        HOMEPATH=\
        HOSTNAME=nykpwm2035798
        IDEA_PROPERTIES=C:\Documents and Settings\shankarc\idea.properties
        INFOPATH=/usr/local/info:/usr/share/info:/usr/info:
        JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_21/
        JDK_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\
        LOGONSERVER=\\NYKPSM00069
        MANPATH=/usr/local/man:/usr/share/man:/usr/man::/usr/ssl/man
        NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
        OS=Windows_NT
        PATH=C:\Apps\CYGWIN\usr\local\bin;C:\Apps\CYGWIN\bin;C:\Apps\CYGWIN\bin;C:\Apps\CYGWIN\usr\X11R6\bin;C:\Apps\Apache\apache-ant-1.7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\;C:\Apps\CYGWIN\bin;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin;C:\Program Files\Sudowin\Clients\Console;C:\Program Files\Fortify Software\Fortify 360 v2.5.0\bin
        PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.PSC1
        PRINTER=\\NYKPSM04020\NYKLPR1301-03-03C05
        PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
        PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 6, GenuineIntel
        PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
        PROCESSOR_REVISION=0f06
        PROFGROUP=FONP
        PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files
        PROMPT=$P$G
        PWD=/cygdrive/c/svn/CEL_v3681/gcct/cel
        QHOME=c:\q
        QTJAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_07\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
        SESSIONNAME=Console
        SHLVL=1
        SITECODE=NYK
        SITEIDENT=NYK
        SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK=1
        SYSTEMDRIVE=C:
        SYSTEMROOT=C:\WINNT
        TEMP=C:\TEMP
        TERM=cygwin
        TMP=C:\TEMP
        UATDATA=C:\WINNT\system32\CCM\UATData\D9F8C395-CAB8-491d-B8AC-179A1FE1BE77
        USER=shankarc
        USERDNSDOMAIN=INTRANET.BARCAPINT.COM
        USERDOMAIN=INTRANET
        USERNAME=shankarc
        USERPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\shankarc
        WINDIR=C:\WINNT
        CVS_PASSFILE=C:\Apps\CYGWIN\home\shankarc\.cvspass]

Total time: 58 seconds
```

How I resolve this?

Comment: I am using the cvs which is under "/usr/bin/cvs" CYGWIN folder.

Comment: If type in "cvs checkout -A -rfirst_v2_126 gcct/first" and run, it's successful.  But somehow when ant build tries to run it, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that even though I was not using .cvspass I did have a build property of cvs.pass set which needed to be reset to OVERRIDE to function depending on how you set up your cvs access (though it looked similar from your post). This needed to be changed in build.properties and .build.properties. Hope this helps!